# Graphics.drawImage doesn't draw in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, awt

I am trying to draw images with g.drawImage(), However, it does not display on the screen. So can you please examine my code and tell me what the reason may be?

```
private char enemyBoard[][] = new char[10][10]; 
private Rectangle r[][] = new Rectangle[10][10];
private int size;  
Image img;
public EnemyPanel()
{
    size=Constant.rectSize;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            enemyBoard[i][j]='*'; //initialization type
            r[i][j]= new Rectangle(j*size+30,i*size+30, size, size);         
        }
    }

    img=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("/edu/iyte/ceng316/resource/kurukafa2.jpg";);

}


  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                    g.drawImage(img,(int)r[i][j].getX(),(int)r[i][j].getY(),null);                                                          
            }
        }        
  }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void loadImage()
   {
     try
     {
     img=ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(Constant.kurukafa));
     }
     catch(IOException e)
     {
     e.printStackTrace();
     } 
   }
```

Okey I solved my problem with this.